# When is the Stieltjes integral of bounded variations?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis, bounded-variation

I was trying to figure out when a Riemann or Lebsgue Stieltjes integral is of bounded variation. For simplicity let $f$ be a increasing RCLL function; when is that

$$\int_0^t g(x) df(x)$$ is of bounded variation?

Clearly if $f \in C^1$ this holds, because then the integral is absolutely continuos and therefore of bounded variation.

Are there other easy-to-check sufficient conditions?